# PHP sleep, pcntl_signal, and ticks

Tags: php, sleep, pcntl

Ok, so I've been trying to get [`Process Signals`](http://www.advancedlinuxprogramming.com/alp-folder/alp-ch03-processes.pdf) to work with `PHP` scripts. I've run into a lot of stuff where I am just not sure what is going on, and I feel like the documentation doesn't do a very good job of explaining it.

So let's say I follow the example on [registering signals](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pcntl-signal.php):

```
<?php
// tick use required as of PHP 4.3.0
declare(ticks = 1);

// signal handler function
function sig_handler($signo)
{

     switch ($signo) {
         case SIGTERM:
             // handle shutdown tasks
             exit;
             break;
         case SIGHUP:
             // handle restart tasks
             break;
         case SIGUSR1:
             echo "Caught SIGUSR1...\n";
             break;
         default:
             // handle all other signals
     }

}

echo "Installing signal handler...\n";

// setup signal handlers
pcntl_signal(SIGTERM, "sig_handler");
pcntl_signal(SIGHUP,  "sig_handler");
pcntl_signal(SIGUSR1, "sig_handler");

// or use an object, available as of PHP 4.3.0
// pcntl_signal(SIGUSR1, array($obj, "do_something"));

echo"Generating signal SIGTERM to self...\n";

// send SIGUSR1 to current process id
posix_kill(posix_getpid(), SIGUSR1);

echo "Done\n";

?>
```

However, within my `sig_handler` function, I add an `exit(1)` at the end. Will the `echo "Done\n";` still be executed? I have attempted something similar, albeit in a class structure, and it was- only *before* my `sig_handler` ever got called.

My class `__construct` calls the function `registerSignals`:

```
private function registerSignals(){
    if(function_exists("pcntl_signal")){
        //call_user_func([$this, "sigintCleanup"]);
        pcntl_signal(SIGINT, [$this, "sigintCleanup"]);
        pcntl_signal(SIGTERM, [$this, "sigtermCleanup"]);
        pcntl_signal(SIGHUP, [$this, "sighupCleanup"]);
        pcntl_signal(SIGUSR1, [$this, "sigusr1Cleanup"]);
    }
}

protected function sigintCleanup(){
    echo "In SIGINT cleanup\n";
    $this->cleanup();
}

protected function sigtermCleanup(){
    echo "In SIGTERM cleanup\n";
    $this->cleanup();
}

protected function sighupCleanup(){
    echo "In SIGHUP cleanup\n";
    $this->cleanup();
}

protected function sigusr1Cleanup(){
    echo "In SIGUSR1 cleanup\n";
    $this->cleanup();
}

protected function cleanup(){
    echo "Shutting down\n";
    exit(1);
}
```

And then within my testing of this process, I do some simple `sleep`s and `echo`s (`start` is just a function called after the construction and signal registration is finished):

```
function start(){
    echo "-- Testing the test script --\n";
    sleep(10000);
    echo "given how ticks work, this might not be called...\n";
    echo "\nAfter sleep... this should not be executed if there was a signal interrupt.\n";
}
```

So I use `ctl-c` during the `sleep`. My result?

```
-- Testing the test script --
^Cgiven how ticks work, this might not be called...

After sleep... this should not be executed if there was a signal interrupt.
In SIGINT cleanup
Shutting down
```

As you can see from my `echo`s, I kinda figured maybe the way [ticks](http://www.phpdig.net/ref/rn62.html) work was responsible for finishing the `start` function *before* handling the signal. I still think this might be the case. The truth is, I just don't know.

I do declare `ticks` at the top of my program:

```
declare(ticks = 1);
```

Not handling signals immediately is causing problems for me. What if, for instance, I had this bit of code in my `start` function (and I've tested this)?

```
$count = 0;
while(true){
    count++;
    echo "count\n";
    sleep(5);
}
```

Even if my `cleanup` function has an `exit`, I never reach that because the `SIGINT` just knocks me out of `sleep`, and I continue in the loop and begin `sleep`ing again.

So here's my question: How does `signal` handling work in `PHP`? How can I guarantee that when I get a signal, it is handled immediately? I don't just want some piece of code that will fix this, I would like an *explanation* (or at least a link to a good one and a summary).

PHP version: 5.4.22

OS: Ubuntu 12.10

Comment: I tried quite hard to reproduce your problem, and the only way I managed to see your problem is by setting `ticks` to a value greater than 1. What is your PHP version? OS? Please post your PHP's "Configure Command", as well as a full working code sample that exhibits the unexpected behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

`sleep()` will be knocks out by some signal, and it will return left sleep seconds, you can do something like this to keep it sleep.

```
.....
declare(ticks = 1);

$left = sleep(1000)
while ($left > 0) {
   $left = sleep($left);
}
```